# Collection View Xcode Swift 3 padding and spacing

Tags: xcode, swift3, collectionview

I have this code for a collection view:

```
let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0)
fileprivate let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 3

var items = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

I use this code in sizeforitemAt:

```
//2
    let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (itemsPerRow + 1)
    let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
    let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow
```

However it skips cells and leaves them blank. What I'm looking for is 3 cells per row with 50 padding on top and 1,1,1 on left right and bottom. Can anyone please help me?

Denis

Answer (score 0):

Right now I am also working on the same kind of functionality and this is how I did with my app just now:

```
let numberOfCellsInRow = 3
let cellWidth = (clnViewWidth - leftPadding - rightPadding - (minimumInterItemSpace * (numberOfCellsInRow-1)))/numberOfCellsInRow
```

Hope this would be helpful. Let me know if you need help as I am doing same with portrait and landscape modes.

Comment: Hey thanks alot man, I'll let you know if it works out for me